# Как присвоить значения ключей списку

Tags: python

У меня есть список и словарь

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'a']

dict = {'*': 'a', 'd': 'b', '%': 'c', '#': 'd'}
```

Мне нужно чтобы в итоге из abacabadaba получилось

```
*d*%*d*#*d*
```

Comment: как получилось d%d#d?

Answer (score 4):

попробуйте так:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'a']

dict = {'*': 'a', 'd': 'b', '%': 'c', '#': 'd'}

dict = {value: key for key, value in dict.items()}

print("".join(dict[el] for el in list))
```

Comment: list и dict - плохие названия для переменных.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru у автора были такие, поэтому я не стал менять